# !Missing $ inserted and _ character in bibliography

Tags: bibtex

I'm having some struggles with an '_' character. Everytime I run my latex document it gives the unhelpful error: "! Missing $ inserted.". After a lot of messing around I found out that it was this reference that is causing it:

```
@article{Nystrom2011,
abstract = {A central problem in cranio-maxillofacial (CMF) surgery is to restore the normal anatomy of the skeleton after defects, e.g., trauma to the face. With careful pre-operative planning, the precision and predictability of the craniofacial reconstruction can be significantly improved. In addition, morbidity can be reduced thanks to shorter operation time. An important component in surgery planning is to be able to accurately measure the extent of anatomical structures. Of particular interest are the shape and volume of the orbits (eye sockets). These properties can be measured in 3D CT images of the skull, provided that an accurate segmentation of the orbits is available. Here, we present a system for interactive segmentation of the orbit in CT images. The system utilizes 3D visualization and haptic feedback to facilitate efficient exploration and manipulation of 3D data. {\textcopyright} 2011 Springer-Verlag.},
author = {Nystr{\"{o}}m, Ingela and Nysj{\"{o}}, Johan and Malmberg, Filip},
doi = {10.1007/978-3-642-25191-7_1},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/jeroe/Documents/Mayo/Paper/Literature/Nystrom 2011.pdf:pdf},
isbn = {9783642251900},
issn = {03029743},
journal = {Lecture Notes in Computer Science (including subseries Lecture Notes in Artificial Intelligence and Lecture Notes in Bioinformatics)},
number = {PART 1},
pages = {1--12},
title = {{Visualization and haptics for interactive medical image analysis: Image segmentation in cranio-maxillofacial surgery planning}},
volume = {7066 LNCS},
year = {2011}
}
@misc{Euro
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I load in an extra package or something?

EDIT: Question edited because I asked the wrong question.
EDIT 2: Changed tag from biblatex to bibtex

Comment: The problem is in the DOI which includes a _ (underscore).

Comment: Are you loading the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages? I see you've selected the `biblatex` tag. If you indeed use the `biblatex` package (along with the `biber` backend program), you shouldn't have to replace umlauts at all - although writing `{\"{o}}` instead of `ö` won't hurt either.

Comment: Please confirm that you use `biblatex` (and `biber`). If you do not, please indicate which tools you use to create the bibliography.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the quick replies. Apologies, should have mentioned it: Mendeley tells me that I'm using 'BibTex', I honestly thought that biblatex was just the tag for latex library.

Comment: @user94293 You were right! it is that! I guess it's not a vital part of my reference so I just changed it, is there a way to 'teach' bibtex what an underscore is?

Comment: If you use `biblatex` an underscore in the `doi` field is OK.

Comment: What bibliography package and which style do you use?

Comment: @moewe See my previous comment I use BibTex (can't choose that's what mendeley my reference generator uses)

Comment: Its not so important what Mendeley tells you, it only tells you the export format. It is much more important what LaTeX packages you use to get your bibliography. They will determine if and how your bibliography can handle underscores.

Comment: Right now I'm loading the natbib package, however that one also had problems with the '_'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, using the `url` package:

```
\usepackage{url}
```

and then in the bib file

```
doi = {\url{10.1007/978-3-642-25191-7_1}},
```

Comment: If the OP indeed used `biblatex` as tagged, then `doi = {10.1007/978-3-642-25191-7_1},` would work out of the box. The `url` package would be loaded automatically. With `biblatex` the DOI and URL fields should contain the raw DOI or URL only, no markup commands.